# How to Handle Iframes in a layer of WebTables

Tags: java, email, xpath, iframe, automation

*Assume the below scenarios:

Below are different webelements on a webpage

Table-->Table-->Table-->Iframe-->Table-->Table-->(Webelement to be handled)

Now I want my selenium Webdriver to get the access of that webelement at the end.

Currently I am not able to get to the element because of these many table layers. IF someone could please help*

Comment: Please post the html code you're dealing with.  You need to write a specific XPath expression to target the webelement (`findElement(By.xpath(...)`).

Comment: @E.Wiest Thnx for your answer. The issue was because I didn't change to the default content before coming to the frame. The issue has been resolved.